# How to select a rows based on column hierachical data

Tags: oracle, group-by

So I am having issues framing this but my table looks like the below:

| Item | LogicA | LogicB | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | NameA | NameAB |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | NameB | NameBC |
| 1 | 3 | 4 | NameC | NameCD |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | NameD | NameDE |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | AAA | RRR |
| 2 | 3 | 3 | BBB | EEE |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | CCC | FFF |
| 2 | 4 | 4 | DDD | WWW |

For each reference value, I want to be able to retrieve the relevant row based on hierarchy on column Logic and LogicB.

For column LogicA, check for the lowest value available and choose the corresponding row.
Similarly for column Logic B look for the lowest value available and choose the relevant row.

The final output should look like below.

| Item | LogicA | LogicB | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 | NameA | NameAB |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | NameB | NameBC |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | AAA | RRR |

For Item 2, there is only 1 row as , both the lowest values for LogicA and Logic B column coincided in the same row. If they are in two different rows, there is be two rows in output as shown for item 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` window function as follows:

```
select t.* from
  (select t.*,
         row_number() over (partition by item order by logicA, logicB) as rn1,
         row_number() over (partition by item order by logicB, logicA) as rn2
   from your_table t) t
where rn1 = 1 or rn2 = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what was looking for, order by using both rows at the same time fixed it, I was doing it one row at a time and it wasn't giving me desired results.